# How to store two separate variables of the same argument in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function in Python which takes in a website name and simply returns two versions of it in two separate variables:

The first variable website should look like the original argument with no changes: http://example.com

The second variable websitefilename should look like this: http-example-com

I have attempted to store these in two separate variables like so:

```
   def websitefile(website):
    
        websitefilename = re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '-', website).strip().lower()
        websitefilename = re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-', website)
    
        print(website)
        print(websitefilename)

websitefile(http://example.com)
```

But both website and websitefilename- return the same thing:

http://example.com

How do you make website return http://example.com and websitefilename return http-example-com?

I need them differently because Windows for some reason can't have slashes in filenames.

Comment: Please share your real code (or an MRE that you can run yourself that reproduces the problem).  Aside from the indentation being off, what you're calling `websitefile` with isn't a valid expression, so it's clear that you haven't tried running this code.

Comment: Nonsense, pointless comment, the commenters below managed to do it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def websitefile(website):
    # Your first regex expression
    websitefilename = re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '-', website).strip().lower()

    # Your second expression was operating on website, not websitefilename as intended.
    websitefilename = re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-', websitefilename)

    # Return a tuple containing the original version and the santitized version
    return website, websitefilename 

# Run the function, collecting the two strings as a tuple
res_tup = websitefile("http://example.com")
print(f"{res_tup=}")
print(f"{res_tup[0]=}")
print(f"{res_tup[1]=}\n")

# Re-run the function, collecting the two strings as separate variables
website, filename = websitefile("http://example.com")
print(f"{website=}")
print(f"{filename=}")
```

Output:

```
res_tup=('http://example.com', 'http-example-com')
res_tup[0]='http://example.com'
res_tup[1]='http-example-com'
 
website='http://example.com'   
filename='http-example-com'
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 3 of your code you should use `websitefilename` instead of `website`

Below code should work

```py
import re

def websitefile(website):

    websitefilename = re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '-', website).strip().lower()
    websitefilename = re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-', websitefilename)

    print(website)
    print(websitefilename)

websitefile("http://example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

your second regex replace is incorrect. It should be
websitefilename = re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-', websitefilename)

with that your output is :
http://example.com
http-example-com